# Enable autoplay function in COMPACT NEWS PREVIEWER WITH JQUERY

Tags: jquery, slider, carousel

Can any one please suggest me how do I enable autoplay function in the News Slider?

[COMPACT NEWS PREVIEWER WITH JQUERY](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/10/03/compact-news-previewer)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: No. I dont know how to code Jquery. :(

Comment: I tried adding multiple jquery autoplay functions but didint work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick

test it in the google chrome console [here](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CompactNewsPreviewer/)

```
i=1;
x=0;
function next() {
    i++;
    if(i== $('.cn_item.selected').parent('.cn_page').children().length){      
        if($('#cn_next').hasClass('disabled')){
            prev_call=$('#cn_list').children('.cn_page').length;
            for(j=0;j<prev_call;j++){
                $('#cn_prev').click();
            }
        }else{
            $('#cn_next').click();
        }
        x=1;
        $('.cn_page').each(function(){
            if($(this).css('display') == 'block'){
                $(this).children().first().addClass('selected').click();
            }
        });
        i=0;
    }
    if(x == 0){
        $('.cn_item.selected').removeClass('selected').next('div').addClass('selected').click();
    }else{
        x=0;
    }
}
setInterval(next, 2000);
```

Comment: But if I click on 4th slide (last slide), it stops working.. :(

Comment: yes it's auto-play can't be controlled if clicked manually as you asked for auto-play.

Comment: welcome it took around 40 min for making this code as i studied the whole concept and they finally made it work with lots if testing. You can make another question for making it work also manually .

Comment: Oh great!! It was quick..Making some changes right now..will surely make another question to make it work manually. :)